# How to select option in drop down protractorjs e2e tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I am trying to select an option from a drop down for the angular e2e tests using protractor.

Here is the code snippet of the select option:

```
<select id="locregion" class="create_select ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="" ng-disabled="organization.id !== undefined" ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in organizations" ng-model="organization.parent_id">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="0">Ranjans Mobile Testing</option>
    <option value="1">BeaverBox Testing</option>
    <option value="2">BadgerBox</option>
    <option value="3">CritterCase</option>
    <option value="4">BoxLox</option>
    <option value="5">BooBoBum</option>
</select>
```

I have tried:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('select option:1')).click();
```

**This gives me the following error:**

An invalid or illegal string was specified
Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

I have also tried:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/ng-include/div/div[2]/div/div/organization-form/form/div[2]/select/option[3]')).click();
```

**This gives me the following error:**

> ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>   Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.35.0', revision: 'c916b9d', time: '2013-08-12 15:42:01'
>   System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
>   Session ID: bdeb8088-d8ad-0f49-aad9-82201c45c63f
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=MAC, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=24.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]

Can anyone please help me with this problem or throw some light on what i might be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and eventually wrote a helper function that selects dropdown values.

I eventually decided that I was fine selecting by option number, and therefore wrote a method that takes an element and the optionNumber, and selects that optionNumber.  If the optionNumber is null it selects nothing (leaving the dropdown unselected).

```
var selectDropdownbyNum = function ( element, optionNum ) {
  if (optionNum){
    var options = element.all(by.tagName('option'))   
      .then(function(options){
        options[optionNum].click();
      });
  }
};
```

I wrote a blog post if you want more detail, it also covers verifying the text of the selected option in a dropdown: http://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/protractor-and-dropdowns-validation/

Comment: Didn't work for me, got element.findElements is not a function.

Comment: even if it works, there are multiple problems with this code. 1. It's not clear why variable `options` is created if the output of the command is always `undefined`. 2. For getting one element out of elementArrayFinder, it's better (and easier) to use .get() method. 3. If you pass an element to the function, then `element.all` statement won't work. 4. It's better to use `async` functions these days. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110526/9150146

Answer (score 258):

For me worked like a charm

```
element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'BeaverBox Testing')).click();
```

Comment: Minor note - v0.22 only (I just went to replace my code with this today, and had to upgrade to get it)

Comment: Is there a way for targeting elements using this? Such as having duplicate State select menus.

Comment: Christopher, `ElementFinder` is chain-able, so you can do: `element(by.css('.specific-select')).element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'BeaverBox Testing')).click();`

Comment: Note that you can get partial matches, so 'Small' will match 'Extra Small'.

Comment: To add to TrueWill's comment: The down side of this solution is that if you have two similar options it will use the last found option - which threw up errors based on the wrong selection. What worked for me was http://stackoverflow.com/a/25333326/1945990

Comment: Using this method the value of `form.$pristine` was not updated . Using the `sendKeys()` way  worked ok for me.

Comment: If a partial match is a problem, you can use a RegExp instead of a string.

Answer (score 32):

**An elegant approach** would involve *making an abstraction* similar to what other selenium language bindings offer out-of-the-box (e.g. `Select` class in Python or Java).

Let's make a *convenient wrapper* and hide implementation details inside:

```
var SelectWrapper = function(selector) {
    this.webElement = element(selector);
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.getOptions = function() {
    return this.webElement.all(by.tagName('option'));
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.getSelectedOptions = function() {
    return this.webElement.all(by.css('option[selected="selected"]'));
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.selectByValue = function(value) {
    return this.webElement.all(by.css('option[value="' + value + '"]')).click();
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.selectByPartialText = function(text) {
    return this.webElement.all(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click();   
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.selectByText = function(text) {
    return this.webElement.all(by.xpath('option[.="' + text + '"]')).click();   
};

module.exports = SelectWrapper;
```

Usage example (note how readable and easy-to-use it is):

```
var SelectWrapper  = require('select-wrapper');
var mySelect = new SelectWrapper(by.id('locregion'));

# select an option by value
mySelect.selectByValue('4');

# select by visible text
mySelect.selectByText('BoxLox');
```

Solution taken from the following topic: [Select -> option abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723419/select-option-abstraction).

---

FYI, created a feature request: [Select -> option abstraction](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2361).

Comment: Why do you use 'return' in the select funtions? Is that necessary?

Comment: @Michiel good point. Might be necessary if you want to explicitly resolve the promise returned by `click()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

```
element(by.model('parent_id')).sendKeys('BKN01');
```

Comment: It is the most correct for me. With cssContainingText not you make sure to capture the desired field. Just think if you have 2 selectbox with the same values. +1

Comment: Sorry, what is BKN01?

Comment: @Gerfried BKN01 is the text which you want to select from the drop down.

Comment: @GalBracha Sorry didn't get you

Comment: If you have another option which share same prefex as BKN01, it will not work. A random one will be picked up.

Comment: This probably will not work in Angular 2+ applications where `model` and `binding` are not available. Still.

Answer (score 15):

To access a specific option you need to provide the nth-child() selector:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('select option:nth-child(1)')).click();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @jpw is my answer wrong. or is it simply the formulation of my answer thats wrong?

Comment: The formulation of an answer as a question is why. I don't know if it's the correct answer. If it is you should formulate it as such.

Comment: @bekite Didn't work for me.Still getting the error Element Not visible error when i tried your suggestion

Answer (score 8):

This is how i did my selection.

```
function switchType(typeName) {
     $('.dropdown').element(By.cssContainingText('option', typeName)).click();
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did it:

```
$('select').click();
$('select option=["' + optionInputFromFunction + '"]').click();
// This looks useless but it slows down the click event
// long enough to register a change in Angular.
browser.actions().mouseDown().mouseUp().perform();
```

Comment: To wait for angular to finish up pending processing, use protractor's `waitForAngular()` method.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it is working for me:

```
element(by.model('formModel.client'))
    .all(by.tagName('option'))
    .get(120)
    .click();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this hope it will work

```
element.all(by.id('locregion')).then(function(selectItem) {
  expect(selectItem[0].getText()).toEqual('Ranjans Mobile Testing')
  selectItem[0].click(); //will click on first item
  selectItem[3].click(); //will click on fourth item
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to set an option element:

```
var select = element(by.model('organization.parent_id'));
select.$('[value="1"]').click();
```

Comment: var orderTest = element(by.model('ctrl.supplier.orderTest'))
orderTest.$('[value="1"]').click();

am getting error By(css selector, [value="3"])

Answer (score 3):

To select items (options) with unique ids like in here:

```
<select
    ng-model="foo" 
    ng-options="bar as bar.title for bar in bars track by bar.id">
</select>
```

I'm using this:

```
element(by.css('[value="' + neededBarId+ '"]')).click();
```

Answer (score 3):

We wrote a library which includes 3 ways to select an option:

```
selectOption(option: ElementFinder |Locator | string, timeout?: number): Promise<void>

selectOptionByIndex(select: ElementFinder | Locator | string, index: number, timeout?: number): Promise<void>

selectOptionByText(select: ElementFinder | Locator | string, text: string, timeout?: number): Promise<void>
```

Additional feature of this functions is that they wait for the element to be displayed before any action on the `select` is performed.

You can find it on npm [@hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper).
Typings for TypeScript are provided as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not super elegant, but efficient:

```
function selectOption(modelSelector, index) {
    for (var i=0; i<index; i++){
        element(by.model(modelSelector)).sendKeys("\uE015");
    }
}
```

This just sends key down on the select you want, in our case, we are using modelSelector but obviously you can use any other selector.

Then in my page object model:

```
selectMyOption: function (optionNum) {
       selectOption('myOption', optionNum)
}
```

And from the test:

```
myPage.selectMyOption(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that solutions that work on regular angular select boxes do not work with Angular Material md-select and md-option using protractor. This one was posted by another, but it worked for me and I am unable to comment on his post yet (only 23 rep points). Also, I cleaned it up a bit, instead of browser.sleep, I used browser.waitForAngular();

```
element.all(by.css('md-select')).each(function (eachElement, index) {
    eachElement.click();                    // select the <select>
    browser.waitForAngular();              // wait for the renderings to take effect
    element(by.css('md-option')).click();   // select the first md-option
    browser.waitForAngular();              // wait for the renderings to take effect
});
```

Comment: I just use this:
`element(by.model('selectModel')).click();  
element(by.css('md-option[value="searchOptionValue"]')).click(); `

Comment: Here's another approach:

`mdSelectElement.getAttribute('aria-owns').then(
            function(val) {
                let selectMenuContainer = element(by.id(val));
                selectMenuContainer.element(by.css('md-option[value="foo"]')).click();
            }
        );`

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with selecting options in Firefox that [Droogans's hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23370177/1216245) fixes that I want to mention here explicitly, hoping it might save someone some trouble: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/480.

Even if your tests are passing locally with Firefox, you might find that they're failing on CircleCI or TravisCI or whatever you're using for CI&deployment. Being aware of this problem from the beginning would have saved me a lot of time:)

Answer (score 1):

I've been trawling the net for an answer on how to select an option in a model dropdown and i've used this combination which has helped me out with Angular material.

```
element(by.model("ModelName")).click().element(By.xpath('xpathlocation')).click();
```

it appears that when throwing the code all in one line it could find the element in the dropdown.

Took a lot of time for this solution I hope that this helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

Helper to set the an option element:

```
selectDropDownByText:function(optionValue) {
            element(by.cssContainingText('option', optionValue)).click(); //optionValue: dropDownOption
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If below is the given dropdown-

```html
            <select ng-model="operator">
            <option value="name">Addition</option>
            <option value="age">Division</option>
            </select>
```

Then protractorjs code can be-

```js
        var operators=element(by.model('operator'));
      operators.$('[value=Addition]').click();
```

Source-https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/600

Answer (score 1):

Select option by Index:

```
var selectDropdownElement= element(by.id('select-dropdown'));
selectDropdownElement.all(by.tagName('option'))
      .then(function (options) {
          options[0].click();
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've improved a bit the solution written by PaulL.
First of all I fixed the code to be compatible with the last Protractor API. And then I declare the function in 'onPrepare' section of a Protractor config file as a member of the *browser* instance, so it can be referenced form any e2e spec.

```
  onPrepare: function() {
    browser._selectDropdownbyNum = function (element, optionNum) {
      /* A helper function to select in a dropdown control an option
      * with specified number.
      */
      return element.all(by.tagName('option')).then(
        function(options) {
          options[optionNum].click();
        });
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The below example is the easiest way . I have tested and passed in Protractor Version `5.4.2`

```
//Drop down selection  using option's visibility text 

 element(by.model('currency')).element(by.css("[value='Dollar']")).click();
 Or use this, it   $ isshort form for  .By.css
  element(by.model('currency')).$('[value="Dollar"]').click();
```

---

```
//To select using index

var select = element(by.id('userSelect'));
select.$('[value="1"]').click(); // To select using the index .$ means a shortcut to .By.css
```

Full code

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {

  it('should have a title', function() {

     browser.driver.get('http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/');
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Protractor practice website - Banking App');
    element(by.buttonText('Bank Manager Login')).click();
    element(by.buttonText('Open Account')).click();

    //Drop down selection  using option's visibility text 
  element(by.model('currency')).element(by.css("[value='Dollar']")).click();

    //This is a short form. $ in short form for  .By.css
    // element(by.model('currency')).$('[value="Dollar"]').click();

    //To select using index
    var select = element(by.id('userSelect'));
    select.$('[value="1"]').click(); // To select using the index .$ means a shortcut to .By.css
    element(by.buttonText("Process")).click();
    browser.sleep(7500);// wait in miliseconds
    browser.switchTo().alert().accept();

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## If none of the answer's above worked for you, try this

### works with async/await too

For selecting options by text

```
let textOption = "option2"
await element(by.whichever('YOUR_DROPDOWN_SELECTOR'))
  .getWebElement()
  .findElement(by.xpath(`.//option[text()="${textOption}"]`))
  .click();
```

or by number

```
let optionNumber = 2
await element(by.whichever('YOUR_DROPDOWN_SELECTOR'))
  .getWebElement()
  .findElement(by.xpath(`.//option[${optionNumber}]`))
  .click();
```

Of course you may need to modify the xpath of child options

Don't ask me why, but this is the only way I could automate my dropdowns, when I lost hope already

---

## Update

There was actually one case when even this approach didnt work. THe work around was a bit ugly but worked. I simply had to select the value **two times**

Answer (score 0):

We wanted to use the elegant solution up there using angularjs material but it didnt work because there are actually no option / md-option tags in the DOM until the md-select has been clicked. So the "elegant" way didn't work for us (note angular material!) Here is what we did for it instead, don't know if its the best way but its definately working now

```
element.all(by.css('md-select')).each(function (eachElement, index) {
    eachElement.click();                    // select the <select>
    browser.driver.sleep(500);              // wait for the renderings to take effect
    element(by.css('md-option')).click();   // select the first md-option
    browser.driver.sleep(500);              // wait for the renderings to take effect
});
```

We needed to have 4 selects selected and while the select is open, there is an overlay in the way of selecting the next select. thats why we need to wait 500ms to make sure we don't get into trouble with the material effects still being in action.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set an option element:

```
var setOption = function(optionToSelect) {

    var select = element(by.id('locregion'));
    select.click();
    select.all(by.tagName('option')).filter(function(elem, index) {
        return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
            return text === optionToSelect;
        });
    }).then(function(filteredElements){
        filteredElements[0].click();
    });
};

// using the function
setOption('BeaverBox Testing');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
----------
element.all(by.id('locregion')).then(function(Item)
{
 // Item[x] = > // x is [0,1,2,3]element you want to click
  Item[0].click(); //first item

  Item[3].click();     // fourth item
  expect(Item[0].getText()).toEqual('Ranjans Mobile Testing')


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select dropdown options by value:
`$('#locregion').$('[value="1"]').click();`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to do it by either option value or index**. This example is a bit crude, but it shows how to do what you want:

html:

```
<mat-form-field id="your-id">
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option [value]="1">1</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]="2">2</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```
function selectOptionByOptionValue(selectFormFieldElementId, valueToFind) {

  const formField = element(by.id(selectFormFieldElementId));
  formField.click().then(() => {

    formField.element(by.tagName('mat-select'))
      .getAttribute('aria-owns').then((optionIdsString: string) => {
        const optionIds = optionIdsString.split(' ');    

        for (let optionId of optionIds) {
          const option = element(by.id(optionId));
          option.getText().then((text) => {
            if (text === valueToFind) {
              option.click();
            }
          });
        }
      });
  });
}

function selectOptionByOptionIndex(selectFormFieldElementId, index) {

  const formField = element(by.id(selectFormFieldElementId));
  formField.click().then(() => {

    formField.element(by.tagName('mat-select'))
      .getAttribute('aria-owns').then((optionIdsString: string) => {
        const optionIds = optionIdsString.split(' ');

        const optionId = optionIds[index];
        const option = element(by.id(optionId));
        option.click();
      });
  });
}

selectOptionByOptionValue('your-id', '1'); //selects first option
selectOptionByOptionIndex('your-id', 1); //selects second option
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static selectDropdownValue(dropDownLocator,dropDownListLocator,dropDownValue){
    let ListVal ='';
    WebLibraryUtils.getElement('xpath',dropDownLocator).click()
      WebLibraryUtils.getElements('xpath',dropDownListLocator).then(function(selectItem){
        if(selectItem.length>0)
        {
            for( let i =0;i<=selectItem.length;i++)
               {
                   if(selectItem[i]==dropDownValue)
                   {
                       console.log(selectItem[i])
                       selectItem[i].click();
                   }
               }            
        }

    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom DropDown class for this and add a method as:

```
async selectSingleValue(value: string) {
        await this.element.element(by.xpath('.//option[normalize-space(.)=\'' + value + '\']')).click();
    }
```

Also, to verify what value is currently selected, we can have:

```
async getSelectedValues() {
        return await this.element.$('option:checked').getText();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple one line answer in which angular has special locator which can help to select and index from list.

```
element.all(by.options('o.id as o.name for o in organizations')).get(Index).click()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26301327)

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for **Angular Material**

```
element(by.css("mat-select[formcontrolname=myMatSelect]")).sendKeys(valueToSet);
```

It should not set the "valueToSet" if it's not present in your options.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to select an option using the index I have found is,

```
var selectDropdownElement = await element(by.xpath("Some Xpath"));
                await selectDropdownElement.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function (options) {
                        options[index].click();
                });
```

'index' is the option number which you want to click

Answer (score -1):

**Select the option by CSS property**

```
element(by.model("organization.parent_id")).element(by.css("[value='1']")).click();
```

or

```
element(by.css("#locregion")).element(by.css("[value='1']")).click();
```

Where locregion(id), organization.parent_id(model name) are the attributes of select element.

Answer (score -1):

You can select drop down options like this:

```
element(by.xpath(
'//*[@id="locregion"]//option[contains(text(),"Ranjans Mobile Testing")]'
)).click();
```