# AngularJS + Protractor How to select Dropdown option based on its text not value

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to click on item by it's text and not by it's value from dropdown box.

i found this great post : https://coderwall.com/p/tjx5zg but it doesn't work as expected, the search continue forever after match was found and it is not clicking the item,

if someone have better example (a working one) or can fix this code and make it work,

i will apperciate.

This is the code Dan Haller from the post used (all rights reserved to him)

```
function selectOption(selector, item){
    var selectList, desiredOption;

    selectList = this.findElement(selector);
    selectList.click();

    selectList.findElements(protractor.By.tagName('option'))
        .then(function findMatchingOption(options){
            options.some(function(option){
                option.getText().then(function doesOptionMatch(text){
                    if (item === text){
                        desiredOption = option;
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            });
        })
        .then(function clickOption(){
            if (desiredOption){
                desiredOption.click();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is a select item function that I can use like this:

```
var browser = protractor.getInstance();
browser.selectOption = selectOption.bind(browser);
browser.selectOption(protractor.By.id('my-dropdown'), 'My Value');
```

Comment: I also tried "protractor.By.xpath('select option[text()="Option 2"]'));" and it didn't worked

Comment: I generally use `sendKeys()`, I'm not sure if this is desired or not. For instance if I have a dropdown with a list of city names I would use `elem.sendKeys(desiredCityName)` and it automatically selects the right option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This function selects the 3rd option of your select box.

```
function selectDropdownByNumber(element, index, milliseconds) {
    element.findElements(by.tagName('option'))
      .then(function(options) {
        options[index].click();
      });
    if (typeof milliseconds !== 'undefined') {
      browser.sleep(milliseconds);
   }
}
var mySelect = $('#my-dropdown');
selectDropdownByNumber(mySelect, 2);
```

More info can be found here - http://qainsight.blogspot.fr/2014/04/select-dropdown-value-in-protractor-js.html

Comment: This might have to do with the version of Protractor, but for me the method "findElements" does not work. There is a method called "all" that does the job though.

Answer (score 24):

This question is similar to: [How to select option in drop down protractorjs e2e tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599450/how-to-select-option-in-drop-down-protractorjs-e2e-tests/20308276#20308276)

So long as you're on a recent version of protractor, you can just do:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'BeaverBox Testing')).click();
```

If you want to click by number, you can do:

```
var selectDropdownbyNum = function ( element, optionNum ) {
  if (optionNum){
    var options = element.findElements(by.tagName('option'))   
      .then(function(options){
        options[optionNum].click();
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: I tried this way. But it says could not find the element. Not visible

Comment: `cssContainingText` works for me. this is the correct answer. see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24259419/1068746

Comment: even though I can verify I can get the dropdown element i still get [object Object] has no method 'findElements'  I think it's because i'm doing a direct connect to chrome and not a standalone selenium server

Comment: element(by.cssContaining‌​Text('option', '....')).click();
                                ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 5):

As you want to select option by value, you can use:

```
var select = element.one(by.model('selectData'));
select.$('[label="Option 1"]').click();
```