# Protractor - Element Not Visible when selecting Drop down.(but visible when selected manually)

Tags: automation, protractor, angularjs-e2e

i have been searching for 2 days but i couldnt come to a solution, i want a drop down to be selected. When i click on the drop down using some element.all css locator it clicks on the drop down(Drop down Opens up but error displayed). so i tried to use linkText to open up the drop down(Opens up perfectly). But after that i was not able to select the option in the drop down. (Element Not Visible displayed). also i was not able to select the option through the linkText. below r the details

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:0px">
 <li>
    <div uib-dropdown="" style="margin-right: 5px;" class="dropdown">
                                Tenant
    <a href="" id="simple-dropdown" uib-dropdown-toggle="" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="breadcrumb ng-binding" style="padding-bottom: 2px; padding-top: 2px;">cust1</span>
    </a>
      <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
    <!-- ngRepeat: tenant in tenantList --><li ng-repeat="tenant in tenantList" class="ng-scope">
    <a ng-click="selectTenant(0)" href="">
    <span ng-show="selectedTenant.Identity == tenant.Identity" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    <span ng-show="selectedTenant.Identity != tenant.Identity" style="margin-left: 17px" class="ng-hide"></span>
    <span class="ng-binding">cust1</span>
    </a>
    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in tenantList --><li ng-repeat="tenant in tenantList" class="ng-scope">
    <a ng-click="selectTenant(1)" href="">
    <span ng-show="selectedTenant.Identity == tenant.Identity" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok ng-hide"></span>
    <span ng-show="selectedTenant.Identity != tenant.Identity" style="margin-left: 17px" class=""></span>
    <span class="ng-binding">NewTenant1</span>
     </a>
    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in tenantList --><li ng-repeat="tenant in tenantList" class="ng-scope">
    <a ng-click="selectTenant(2)" href="">
    <span ng-show="selectedTenant.Identity == tenant.Identity" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok ng-hide"></span>
    <span ng-show="selectedTenant.Identity != tenant.Identity" style="margin-left: 17px" class=""></span>
    <span class="ng-binding">cust2</span>
    </a>
    </li><!-- end ngRepeat: tenant in tenantList -->
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I tried to do through below ways to select but i cant make it work.

1. wait for the element to become visible.
2. LinkText
3. Options to select. (via repeater name as the option)
   kindly help me out

Comment: Even tried by finding sub elements. 
var el = element(by.binding('selectedTenant.ParentOwnerName')).element(by.css('a[ng-click="selectTenant(2)"]'));
        el.click();

Comment: Did you try clicking on the `anchor` element instead of `list` element? Also you can pass alphabets if its not recognizing in any way using `sendKeys()` function. Thanks

Comment: i am just 2-3 months old to the protractor. correct me if iam wrong. Is this the Anchor element ur coming to tel by.css('[ng-click‌​="selectTenant(2)"]'). if yes then i tried this. yea i tried sendkeys too. i dono how to pass alphabets. pls explain more precisely

Comment: <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:0px"> added 2 more lines. I guess we have to first switch it over to the div then we need to click on the drop down element to work. If my guess is correct can some 1 tell me how to do it.

Comment: Is your site on public domain and can we access it? I am not sure why you are not able to click on the dropdown, but there are so many answers in stackoverflow that show how to select a value from the dropdown. None of them worked? Here are few - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599450/how-to-select-option-in-drop-down-protractorjs-e2e-tests or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895281/angularjs-protractor-how-to-select-dropdown-option-based-on-its-text-not-value and lot more. Let me know if none of them worked. Thanks

Comment: No it is not in public domain. when i click using index. it displays click is not defined. but now it is working with partialLinkText. thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

element(by.partialLinkText('cust2')); i dono how come linktext is not working but partialLinkText is working. thanks for replies.

Answer (score -1):

Would this suffice? I use this to identify dropdown elements which contain a specific label value...

```
this.clickDropChoice = function(dropdown, optionChoice) {
    dropdown.element(by.cssContainingText('option', optionChoice)).click()
};
```

Comment: ReferenceError: attribute is not defined. wats use in adding attribute in front. do i need to do any more.
Common.Tenant.click();
        browser.sleep(4000);
        attribute.element(by.cssContainingText('div.dropdown', "cust2")).click();
        browser.sleep(4000);

Comment: My appologies, it was from a helper file and I forgot to mention the parameters I use... Basically everywhere in my code I want to click on a dropdown I just call this helper file function :) Ive edited it to contain the appropriate parameters, and tried to label them a little more clearly :)

Comment: hi @TesterPhi do i need to pass dropdown argument with elements??. r can u explain bit clear. sorry

Comment: dropdown is your dropdown menu identifier, optionChoice is what you would like to select. identifer for you would be the id of the dropdown:
element(by.id('simple-dropdown'));
optionchoice would be the text displayed within the option choice you would like to click

Comment: im sorry again can u look at the below code. this is wat i have done but test getting passed but without selecting the drop down.
'var test = element(by.id('simple-dropdown'));
        this.clickDropChoice = function(test, cust2)
        {
            dropdown.element(by.cssContainingText('option', cust2)).click()
        };' 
@TesterPhi am i doing anything wrong. and FYI clickDropChoice is unused it seems.

Comment: What would be for option and optionchoice now i made this clickdropchoice to a new js file so that i wll cal this for drop down. 

dropdown.js ----
this.clickDropChoice = function(dropdown, value)

{
        dropdown.element(by.cssContainingText('option', value)).click();
 };

and i have called this function like  drop.clickDropChoice(Common.Tenantdrop,"cust2"); ---- im getting error like NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("option", "cust2")

Comment: It looks like Common.Tenantdrop isnt on your page, what is Common.Tenantdrop? Technically if you pass in:
`element(by.id('simple-dropdown'))` instead of common.tenantdrop it will target the drop down menu. and then the value (cust2) will target the field within that dropdown... the click will then select it

Comment: Common.Tenantdrop is just the same. i have assigned it in Tenantdrop in common js page. it is displaying the following error. NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText("option", "cust2")

Comment: <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right:0px"> added 2 more lines. I guess we have to first switch it over to the div then we need to click on the drop down element to work. If my guess is correct can some 1 tell me how to do it.