# How to test a Angular js date picker from Protractor

Tags: datepicker, protractor

I'm new to Protractor and here I'm trying to test an angularjs date picker from Protractor.

I tried to find a way to do this and [this article](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-angulardatepicker) was the only thing I found and It is not very clear to use

If someone know how to test please help.

**What I need is to select today's date.**

Thanks in advance :)

- edit -

alecxe, here is the screen shot of my date picker. Unfortunately cannot provide the link of the page. :(

[image: date picker]

```
<input 
       class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" 
       ng-model="invoice.fromdate" 
       data-date-format="yyyy-MM-dd" 
       data-date-type="string" 
       data-max-="" data-autoclose="1" 
       bs-datepicker="" 
       ng-change="dateRange()" 
       type="text">
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo page with the date picker you want to work with through protractor?

Comment: @ alecxe, added. Please look at the edited answer :)

Comment: If you are looking to Automate Angular Material Datepicker then Watch this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8QRDQjt5lw&t=6s

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can avoid manipulating the datepicker manually and instead set the date either by just *sending the keys with a [today's date value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929629/771848)*:

```
var picker = element(by.model("invoice.fromdate"));

// get today's date
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;

picker.clear();
picker.sendKeys(today);
```

Or, by [setting the associated model's value directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34878506/771848):

```
picker.evaluate("invoice.fromdate= '" + today + "'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. Anywy, when I'm trying option 2 gives an error called, today is not  defined. but, option 1 worked as expected. :)

Comment: Could be use below code snipped to save some line

    (new Date).toLocaleDateString();

    mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

Two methods have been suggested so far: 1. sendKeys()  2. evaluate()
I'm a bit new to protractor but I think both of these have issues in the case of not having an input element that spawns the calendar, i.e.:
[image: standalone datepicker]

Sendkeys() works only if date is on an  element and the uib-datepicker is a dropdown sort of deal.  This didn't help me because my datepicker element is a standalone and isn't paired with an input element.
evaluate() doesn't update angular's actual model in the browser (which begs the question of how useful evaluate actually is...).  According protractor [docs](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate), evaluate, "Evaluates the input **as if** it were on the scope of the current underlying elements."  In my case I want to test whether the date generated by the datepicker gets to my enpdpoint via a post request and then back again (hence e2e) without getting effed (corrupted), therefore, I need my date to be on my angular model in the browser instance, not just in the browser-driver environment or whatever the runtime environment of the protractor test is.  I could be wrong about this.
This expect() passes but the ng-form is invalid (i'm assuming b/c model in browser wan't actually updated to receive the date I'm trying to pass in.):

```
function convertToPickerDate(date) {
    var date = new Date(date);
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    var yy = yyyy.toString().slice(2);

    return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy;
}     

// expect passes, but form is invalid - DON'T USE for standalone cal
it('should enter start date in date picker', function () {
        offerStart = convertToPickerDate(myData.startDate);
        var offerStartPicker = element(by.model('current.startDate'));
        offerStartPicker.evaluate("current.startDate = '" + offerStart + "'");
        offerStartPicker.evaluate("current.startDate").then(function (value) {
            expect(value).toBe(offerStart);
        });
})
```

but the ng-form that the element is on is invalid...

My solution uses css selection and arrow keys to select a date relative to today:

```
Shipment Start Date: <em id="offerStartPrint">{{current.startDate | date:'shortDate' }}</em>
<div id="offerStart"
        name="offerStart"
        uib-datepicker
        ng-model="current.startDate"
        class=""
        ng-change="setStartDate()"
        datepicker-options="startDateOptions"
        required></div>
</div>

function convertToPickerDate(date) {
    var date = new Date(date);
    var dd = date.getDate();
    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
    var yy = yyyy.toString().slice(2);

    return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yy;
}

it('should enter expiration date in date picker using tabs and arrows :)', function () {
        // select today element on uib-datepicker calendar
        // div#offerStart elem has date model
        var calToday = element(by.css('div#offerStart table td button.active')); 

        calToday.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN);  // one week away
        calToday.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN);  // two weeks away
        calToday.click(); // if you remove this click no date is entered
        var fortnightAway = new Date(Date.now() + 12096e5);
        fortnightAwayString = convertToPickerDate(fortnightAway);
        expect(element(by.id('offerStartPrint')).getText()).toBe(fortnightAwayString);
    })
```

Left and right arrows can be used to increment/decrement date by one day at a time.
up/down arrows can be used to inc/dec one week at a time.
One could probably figure out how to arrow through months and years as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data_picker = element(by.model("invoice.fromdate"));

// select current date with date function

var current_date = new Date();

var day = today.getDate();

var month = today.getMonth()+1; //By default January count as 0

var year = today.getFullYear();

if(day<10) {
    day='0'+day
} 

if(month<10) {
    month='0'+month
} 

current_date = month+'/'+day+'/'+year;

data_picker.clear();  // Note if you are facing error message related to clear. Comment this line

data_picker.sendKeys(today);

Hope this will work
```

Comment: add some explanation