# Get today's date print to the console in Protractor

Tags: datepicker, protractor

I'm new to Protractor. I need to  select today's date from the date picker.

Is there a specific anyway to select the today's date from the date picker?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36259277/how-to-select-todays-date-from-a-calender-using-protractor/36259343#36259343)

If you need to be more quick,

```
 var pickerDue = element(by.model("supplier.enroll_date"));

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

pickerDue.clear();
pickerDue.sendKeys(today);
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this. :)

Comment: this is what I needed. Thanks. :)

Comment: Okay. U can accept my answer then. It will be easy to others to find the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This method will give you current date time with seconds:

```
getCurrentDatemmddyyyy: function () {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  var hh = today.getHours();
  var mins = today.getMinutes();
  var ss = today.getSeconds();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = "0" + dd;
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = "0" + mm;
  }
  if (hh < 10) {
    hh = "0" + hh;
  }
  if (mins < 10) {
    mins = "0" + mins;
  }

  if (ss < 10) {
    ss = "0" + ss;
  }

  var today = mm + dd + yyyy + hh + mins + ss;
  return today;

},
```