# how to test mobiscroll date-time picker in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, mobiscroll

I'm new to the whole concept of e2e testing and Protractor, so please bear with me..
I'm trying to write an e2e testing script for a form using protractor, but one of the fields being a mobiscroll date-time picker, I'm not able to insert any value into it, by using the conventional .sendKeys() method.
I even tried the approach suggested in this post - [How to test a Angular js date picker from Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860488/how-to-test-a-angular-js-date-picker-from-protractor) but I've not been able to make it work. I need some solution that is mobiscroll date-time picker specific. Please help!!

Comment: can you share the relevant HTML code for the calendar element?

Comment: Yes please share the relevant HTML, and more information as to why it's not working.  What have you tried and what errors are you getting?