# How to test a datepicker with protractor?

Tags: datepicker, protractor, angular5, e2e-testing

I have been trying to make my protractor test on a datepicker work.
I have the following in my html file

```
<div fxFlex>
    <mat-datepicker #pickerBirthdate></mat-datepicker>
    <input matInput
           style="visibility: hidden;"
           [min]="minBirthdate"
           [max]="maxBirthdate"
           [matDatepicker]="pickerBirthdate"
           placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento"
           [(ngModel)]="registry.data.fechaNac"
           name="fechaNac">
</div>
```

And the following on my spec file

```
expect(page.getElementByClass('.date-select-picker'));
// get today's date
let today: any = new Date();
let dd: any = today.getDate();
let mm: any = today.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0!
const yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
  dd = '0' + dd;
}

if ( mm < 10) {
  mm = '0' + mm;
}
today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
  page.sleep();
  page.getElementByClass('.date-select-picker').sendKeys(today);`
```

The problem is, it doesn't show up any date it just looks raised.

I've read this threads but I haven't been able to make it work, I don't know if it's due to my angular version.

- [How to test a Angular js date picker from Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860488/how-to-test-a-angular-js-date-picker-from-protractor)
- https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10404

Thanks in advance and good day

Comment: For testing datepicker you have to do the same as for every other component. Open the datepicker and copy it's html and create css selectors in protractor for it using `element()`, `sendKeys()` and `click()`  :)
Can you explain me following line in your code ? => . `expect(page.getElementByClass('.date-select-picker'));`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I quit working at the place where I was having this problem and I can't see the code anymore.

Comment: If you are looking to Automate Angular Material Datepicker then Watch this video youtube.com/watch?v=T8QRDQjt5lw&t=6s

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the datepicker, this is how I select a date in the future:

```
    /// click the datepicker
    element(by.css('.mat-datepicker-toggle')).click();

    /// opens the table with years
    element(by.css('.mat-calendar-arrow')).click();

    /// select year, month and day
    element(by.cssContainingText(".mat-calendar-body-cell-content", "2040")).click();        
    element(by.cssContainingText(".mat-calendar-body-cell-content", "DEC.")).click();        
    element(by.cssContainingText(".mat-calendar-body-cell-content", "31")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

use the harness:

```
const harnessLoader = ProtractorHarnessEnvironment.loader();

const matDatepickerToggleHarness = await harnessLoader.getHarness<MatDatepickerToggleHarness>(
  MatDatepickerToggleHarness.with({selector: 'mat-datepicker-toggle'})
);
await matDatepickerToggleHarness.openCalendar();
```

Comment: In my case, I was getting this error: `Failed to find element matching one of the following queries: (MatCalendarHarness with host element matching selector: ".mat-calendar" satisfying the constraints: host matches selector "#mat-datepicker-0")` and I updated the `MatDatepickerInputHarness` to `MatDatepickerToggleHarness`