# Protractor - assert the evaluate() value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, cucumber, protractor

I tried to evalaute a angular variable in protractor using "evaluate()" and got the value. How do I verify

```
element.evaluate('angularObj').then(function(angularObj) {
    expect(angularObj.type).to.equal('myType');     
});
```

But it says

> TypeError: 'kitchen' is not a thenable.

`kitchen` is the value in `angularObj.type`

How can i assert the value in protractor?

Answer (score 1):

`.then()` is a chaining functionality used whenever a promise is returned by a function in protractor. [`.evaluate()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) function returns an `ElementFinder` and not a value, so it cannot be chained. Here's how to use it -

```
var ele = element.evaluate('angularObj')
expect(ele.type).to.equal('myType');
```

Though i haven't tried this, but it should work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You better try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078955/setting-an-angular-model-using-protractor/34878506#34878506) alecxe's answer for better solution about evaluate() value.

```
elm.evaluate("<model of your element>").then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

or

```
var elm = element(by.model("<model of your element>"));
elm.evaluate("<model of your element> = 'test';");
```

Hope this helps. :)