# How to click on option in select box in Protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

I am using Protractor for end to end testing in Angular application. I am trying to click on option in select box, but i have folowing error **Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated.**

I have this part of html:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-model="selectedAction.begStatus"
        ng-options="obj as obj.name for obj in allBegStatuses">
</select>
```

And I have this line of code in Protractor test:

```
element(by.xpath('//select/option[text()="Draft"]')).click();
```

I want to click on option with value "Draft". Do you know maybe what is the problem?

Comment: why don't you want to select element by model?

Comment: You should use the options locator. EG: `element.all(by.options('obj as obj.name for obj in allBegStatuses'))`; [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412256/protractor-unable-to-select-dropdown-option/33422130#33422130) can show you how to apply a filter in the option list.

Answer (score 4):

```
var option = element.all(by.options('obj as obj.name for obj in allBegStatuses'));
var selectOption = option.get(1);
selectOption.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a function for select(by id) and clicks an option by text compare.

```
this.selectOption = function (selector, item) {
        var selectList, desiredOption;
        selectList = element(by.id(selector));
        selectList.all(protractor.By.tagName('option'))
            .then(function (options) {
                options.some(function (option) {
                    option.getText().then(function (text) {
                        if (item.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()) {
                            desiredOption = option;
                            return true;
                        }
                        return true;
                    });
                });
            })
            .then(function () {
                if (desiredOption) {
                    desiredOption.click();
                }
            });
    };
```

hopefully it works for you to

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="controlId"]/option[3]')).click();
```

This should select the value in the drop down.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if 'Draft' becomes  `option[4]`?

Comment: out of ALL the verbose, cumbersome answers on the web THIS is the solution! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

select by model:

```
element(by.select("selectedAction.begStatus"))
```

Comment: I can do that, but how can I put specific value of option to be clicked? Because I want to click option with value = "Draft" only.

Comment: probably this would help then 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599450/how-to-select-option-in-drop-down-protractorjs-e2e-tests

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I've already tried solutions from this page, and those did not work for me. Dont know is there a possibility for having multiple conditions in one expression, for example to have:
element by model, and by xpath in one expression?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    function selectOptionByText (selectBox, optionText) {
        selectBox.element(by.cssContainingText('option', optionText)).click();
    }
```