# Select -> option abstraction

Tags: python, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In Python, Java and several other selenium bindings, there is a very convenient abstraction over `select->option` HTML constructions, a [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select).

For example, imagine there is the following `select` tag:

```
<select id="fruits" class="select" name="fruits">
    <option value="1">Banana</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>
```

Here is how we can operate it in Python:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('fruits'))

# get all options
print select.options

# get all selected options
print select.all_selected_options

# select an option by value
select.select_by_value('1')

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('Mango')
```

In other words, it is a *very transparent and easy to use abstraction*.

Is is possible to manipulate `select` tag **in protractor** in a similar manner?

---

<sup>This is not a duplicate of [How to select option in drop down protractorjs e2e tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599450/how-to-select-option-in-drop-down-protractorjs-e2e-tests) or [How to click on option in select box in Protractor test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23754743/how-to-click-on-option-in-select-box-in-protractor-test).</sup>

Comment: Why does this need a bounty?

Comment: @tox123 it is my way to say thank you for a good answer.

Comment: Oh in hindsight looking at your rep, you could take -50 points.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No such thing in Protractor, but we can write our own:

**select-wrapper.js**

```
'use strict';

var SelectWrapper = function(selector) {
    this.webElement = element(selector);
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.getOptions = function() {
    return this.webElement.all(by.tagName('option'));
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.getSelectedOptions = function() {
    return this.webElement.all(by.css('option[selected="selected"]'));
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.selectByValue = function(value) {
    return this.webElement.all(by.css('option[value="' + value + '"]')).click();
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.selectByPartialText = function(text) {
    return this.webElement.all(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click();   
};
SelectWrapper.prototype.selectByText = function(text) {
    return this.webElement.all(by.xpath('option[.="' + text + '"]')).click();   
};

module.exports = SelectWrapper;
```

**Usage**

```
var SelectWrapper  = require('select-wrapper');
var mySelect = new SelectWrapper(by.id('fruits'));

# select an option by value
mySelect.selectByValue('1');

# select by visible text
mySelect.selectByText('Mango');
```

Note that **Select** is a [reserved word in JavaScript](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)

Answer (score 1):

Starting [Protractor v.0.22.0](http://ng-learn.org/2014/05/Protractor-0-22-0/) you can just use 
[the new `By.cssContainingText` locator](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/8b088fd6bf83696fd2ad294d8818e20894332693):

```
element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Mango'));
```

[See the API reference](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText).

Answer (score 1):

**Code with Typescript:**

Tagname:

> by.tagName('option')
>
> by.tagName('md-option')
>
> by.tagName('li')

```
selectOption(selector: string, item: string) {
    let selectList: any;
    let desiredOption: any;

    selectList = element(by.css(selector));
    selectList.click();

    selectList.findElements(by.tagName('option'))
        .then(function findMatchingOption(options: any) {
            options.some(function (option: any) {
                option.getText().then(function doesOptionMatch(text: string) {
                    if (item === text) {
                        desiredOption = option;
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            });
        })
        .then(function clickOption() {
            if (desiredOption) {
                desiredOption.click();
            }
        });
}
```

**Used:**

```
selectOption('//select[@id="food"]', 'Pizza');
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to implement it on you own :). We wrote a library which includes 3 ways to select an option:

```
selectOption(option: ElementFinder |Locator | string, timeout?: number): Promise<void>

selectOptionByIndex(select: ElementFinder | Locator | string, index: number, timeout?: number): Promise<void>

selectOptionByText(select: ElementFinder | Locator | string, text: string, timeout?: number): Promise<void>
```

Additional feature of this functions is that they wait for the element to be displayed before any action on the `select` is performed.

You can find it on npm [@hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hetznercloud/protractor-test-helper).
Typings for TypeScript are provided.