# New to Protractor and difficulty with collecting Select options

Tags: angularjs, select, protractor

self teaching protractor and fighting issues of non angular web app and getting the list of all values out of a select control. here is the html but can't seem to validate the list. (first weight select box at this site)

http://halls.md/body-surface-area/bsa.htm

and my failed syntax.  my script executes successfully referencing the element and option but can't correctly evaluate the capture of option values in the list:

```
var tempstr = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//select[@name="wu"]'));  //get all the options
  var tempstrs = tempstr.findElements(by.tagName('option'));
  console.log(tempstrs[1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use `element` notation - would at least look cleaner.

If you want to see the option text or value on the console, you need to resolve promises:

```
var weightUnitSelect = element(by.name("wu"));
var options = weightUnitSelect.all(by.tagName("option"));

options.first().getText().then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Also, I recommend to abstract select->option HTML constructions with the help of this answer:

- [Select -> option abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723419/select-option-abstraction)

Comment: yes, this has helped as I am just learning "locating" options...I was interpreting (name) as an attribute of the Select element and trying to identify with xpath...didn't work.       browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//select[@name="wu"]'));      rather than just locate the element via (name).