# Protractor - Element is not clickable at point (x,y) when using ng-change

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

```
<select id="cbCategory" ui-select2 name="cbCategory" ng-model="categoryCombo.category" 
        class="show-tick form-control comboBlue" ng-change="loadPrice()" required>
    <option ng-repeat="category in Categories" value="{{category}}" 
            {{category.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

When I have select like this, without the `ng-change`, it works in this both solutions:

1.
`element.all(by.repeater('category in Categories').row(0)).click();`

2.
`element(by.id("cbCategory")).sendKeys('Category1');`

But when I have `ng-change` in my select, both solutions are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Click the `select` before clicking an `option`, e.g.:

```
var selectElement = element(by.id("cbCategory"));
selectElement.click();

var option = selectElement.all(by.tagName("option")).first();
option.click();
```

---

You may also want to make working with select->option easier by making an abstraction, see:

- [Select -> option abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723419/select-option-abstraction)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't worked, but on github-protractor issues i got correct answer.
[link] (https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2137)
It had something to do with loadPrice().
Anyway tnx, best regards