# How to get the value from selectbox?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am trying to verify that correct option is selected from selectbox using protractor.

This is how I pick value from selectbox:

```
element(by.id('form-mileage-unit')).click().then(function() {
    element(by.cssContainingText('option', browser.params.lengthUnit)).click();         
});;
```

So base on this I write code below:

```
it('Verify paint color', function() {       
    element(by.id('form-mileage-unit')).click().then(function() {
        element(by.cssContainingText('option', browser.params.lengthUnit).getAttribute("value")).toEqual(browser.params.lengthUnit);            
    });;
});
```

Unfortunately I am getting error:

> TypeError: Object by.cssContainingText("option", "Motohodin") has no method 'getText'

Can someone advise me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the parenthesis in the wrong place and there is no `expect()`. Replace:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('option', browser.params.lengthUnit).getAttribute("value")).toEqual(browser.params.lengthUnit);
```

with:

```
var option = element(by.cssContainingText('option', browser.params.lengthUnit));
expect(option.getAttribute("value")).toEqual(browser.params.lengthUnit);
```

---

If you are dealing with `select->option` constructions a lot, consider using an abstraction over it that would make your tests cleaner and more readable, see:

- [Select -> option abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723419/select-option-abstraction)

Comment: Hi Alecxe, your advise is really clever, finaly had to fix it with getText instead of attribute (becuase it retun just number 2) , but you lead me for correct answer as always.

I will check Select->option possibilitys as well :)