# How to Count Select options in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, select, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I want to count options in select attribute but my test gets failed here is my spec:

```
it('should count the number of option', function()) {

 expect(element(by.id('sorting_options')).all(by.tagName('option').count())).toBe(3);

}
```

it give me Error:

> C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App>protractor conf.js Starting selenium
>   standalone server... [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>   Selenium standalone server started at
>   http://192.168.100.9:12708/wd/hub [launcher] Error:
>   C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App\protractorSpec\spec.js:37   it('should
>   count the number of option',function()){
>                                                      ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is malformed, here is the correct syntax:

```
it('should count the number of option', function () {
    expect(element(by.id('sorting_options')).all(by.tagName('option')).count()).toBe(3);
});
```

Comment: it still not working it give this Error:
C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App>protractor conf.js
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.100.9:18049/wd/hub
Started
......F

Failures:
1) First-angular-App should count the number of option
  Message:
    Failed: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the abstraction/wrapper around the select introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736559/771848):

```
var SelectWrapper  = require('select-wrapper');
var sorting = new SelectWrapper(by.id('sorting_options'));

expect(sorting.getOptions().count()).toEqual(3);
```