# how to test option item in select attribute using protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, html-select

I am trying to test items text in select options but my test gets failed and give me error here is my spec:

it('should test the sorting_options text', function() {

```
  expect(element.all((by.id('sorting_options')).Last().text).toBe('Score');
});
```

here is Error i received :

C: \wamp\ www\ First - angular - App > protractor conf.js

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http: //192.168.100.9:31794/wd/hub
[launcher] Error: C: \wamp\ www\ First - angular - App\ protractorSpec\        spec.js: 38
```

how can in resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show your HTML code.

Comment: @N123 here my html  <select ng-model="sortExpression" class="dropdown" id="sorting_options">
                            <option value="">Please Select for sorting</option>
                            <option value="data.title">Title </option>
                            <option value="data.score">Score</option>
                        </select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = element.all(by.css('.dropdown option'));
expect(list.get(0).getText()).toBe('Please Select for sorting');
expect(list.get(1).getText()).toBe('Title');
expect(list.get(2).getText()).toBe('Score');
```

Answer (score 2):

I would also think about using [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var options = element.all(by.css('.dropdown option')).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});
expect(options).toEqual(["Please Select for sorting", "Title", "Score"]);
```

There is also a convenient wrapper around "select->option" block, which you may use:

- [Select -> option abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723419/select-option-abstraction)