# Using Protractor, how do I get a random select option other that the currently selected one?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to handle a test scenario for a select menu where spec would pick a random option other than the one currently selected. I can't seem to find a working locator or method that would let me do it.

1. Strategy 1: get the current index of `option[selected]` and select random off other indices.
2. Strategy 2: get options not selected `by.css('option:not([selected])')` - get the length of the array and pick random one. This selector seems to ignore the `:not` part and returns total number of options.

As I am fresh to protractor, I don't really see a way to do that looking at the [API](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api). Any hint, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's filter non-selected options using [`.filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
var nonSelectedOptions = $$("option").filter(function (option) {
    return option.isSelected().then(function (isSelected) {
        return !isSelected;
    });;
});
```

Now, we need a list of indexes to choose a random one from, let's use [`.map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var indexes = nonSelectedOptions.map(function (option, index) {
    return index;
});
```

Now, we need to resolve the `indexes` promise to get the array of indexes and use the "picking a random item from an array" solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915122/771848). We are going to use [`.get()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) to get a specific option for the randomly chosen index:

```
indexes.then(function (indexes) {
    var randomIndex = indexes[Math.floor(Math.random()*indexes.length)];

   var randomOption = nonSelectedOptions.get(randomIndex);

   // now select the randomOption
});
```

If you would use the wrapper suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723419/select-option-abstraction), the option selection code would be:

```
randomOption.getAttribute("value").then(function (optionValue) {
    mySelect.selectByValue(optionValue);
});
```

Not tested.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! I will explore the area of wrappers soon when I get more foundation. I would certainly add `SelectWrapper.prototype.selectAnother` function to the wrapper you mention.