# Select a particular option in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm a new born QA and I'm trying here to write a Protractor script to select an option from a dropdown. There are 2 options in my dropdown and I'm trying to select it from number.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
var selectDropdownbyNum = function ( element, optionNum ) {
    if (optionNum){
    var options = element.findElements(by.tagName('entity.company_id as entity.company_name for entity in entities'))   
      .then(function(options){
        options[1].click();
      });
    }
  };
```

Option 2 is selected by default when the page loads. What I need is to select option 1 from the dropdown. But, my code doesn't do that.

Here is the code snippet of the select option.

```
<select required="required" class="form-control empty ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-touched" name="entity_id" ng-model="invoice.entity_id" ng-options="entity.company_id as entity.company_name for entity in entities" ng-required="true" ng-change="entitySelect(invoice.entity_id)">

  <option value="string:568f97841a4885e5de39900e" label="Option Global">Option Global</option>

  <option selected="selected" value="string:568f976a1a4885e5de39900d" label="Option Computer Studies">OptionComputer Studies</option>

</select>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723419/select-option-abstraction. Very convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the perfect answer.

```
element.all(by.css('cssSelector of the dropdown')).each(function (eachElement, index) 
    {
       eachElement.click();// select the <select>
       browser.driver.sleep(500);// wait for the renderings to take effect
       element(by.css('cssSelector of option want to select')).click();// select the first md-option
       browser.driver.sleep(500);// wait for the renderings to take effect
   });
```

This works like calm :)

Comment: Instead of `browser.driver.sleep(500)` you could use `browser.waitForAngular()`.

Comment: It's a bad practice to use browser.sleep() which will prolong test running time. It's recommended to use browser.wait()

Answer (score 2):

var selectDropdownbyNum = function ( dropDown, optionNumber) {

dropDown.click().then(function(){
element.all(by.tagName('entity.company_id as entity.company_name for entity in entities')).first().click();
      });
};

Answer (score 0):

**Got the perfect answer**

var selectOption = element(by.model("invoice.entity_id")).all(by.tagName('option'));
selectOption.get(1).click();

**We can also get all the option value by each function**

selectOption.each(function(item,index){

```
   //Resolve the promise
  item.getText().then(function(data){
       console.log(data+" "+index);
  });
```

});