# Select option by value in Protractor fails

Tags: javascript, protractor, html-select

I'm trying to select an option by option value. In this scenario, I have Categories and sub categories. Here is the application I'm testing using Protractor.

[image: Adding a Category]

[image: Adding a Subcategory]

Here what I'm doing is first add the Category. and I have to refresh the page, because, only if I refresh the page, the added category will be listed in the category drop-down shown in subcategory tab.
 So, after refresh the page I click on subcategory tab and try to fill the fields in subcategory. But, my script fails when selecting the category from options.

Here are the two ways I tried.

Method 1:

```
// Select Category
element.all(by.model('sub_category.category_id')).each(function (eachElement, index)
{
    eachElement.click();
    browser.driver.sleep(500);
    element(by.css('.ng-not-empty > option:nth-child(10)')).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(500);
});
```

Method 2:

```
var select = element(by.model('sub_category.category_id'));
select.$('[value="Test Supplier Category by Me"]').click();
browser.driver.sleep(500);
```

Both methods gives an error called,

> Failed: No element found using locator ...

- Edit -

Here is the HTML

```
<select required="required" class="form-control empty ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" name="category_id" ng-model="sub_category.category_id" ng-options="category.id as category.category for category in categories_index" ng-required="true"><option selected="selected" value="?"></option><option value="string:6" label="Staff Cost">Staff Cost</option><option value="string:7" label="Utility Bill Expenses">Utility Bill Expenses</option><option value="string:8" label="Administrative Expenses">Administrative Expenses</option><option value="string:9" label="Building Rent">Building Rent</option><option value="string:10" label="Professional Charges &amp; Fees">Professional Charges &amp; Fees</option><option value="string:11" label="Vehicle Expenses">Vehicle Expenses</option><option value="string:13" label="Training &amp; Workshop Cost">Training &amp; Workshop Cost</option><option value="string:14" label="Marketing &amp; Promotional Expenses">Marketing &amp; Promotional Expenses</option><option value="string:15" label="Printing &amp; Supplies">Printing &amp; Supplies</option><option value="string:16" label="Fixed Assets">Fixed Assets</option><option value="string:17" label="Finance Cost">Finance Cost</option><option value="string:18" label="Statutory Payments">Statutory Payments</option><option value="string:19" label="Overseas Travelling Expenses">Overseas Travelling Expenses</option><option value="string:20" label="Test Supplier Category By Me">Overseas Travelling Expenses</option></select>
```

When I'm using Metod 1, following error occurs.

```
1) Protractor Demo App should have a title
  Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".ng-not-empty > opti
on:nth-child(10)")
  Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".ng-not-
empty > option:nth-child(10)")
        at new bot.Error (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
actor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
        at C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\eleme
nt.js:674:15
        at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:12
4:15)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:406:9)
    Error
        at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\Manuli\AppD
ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:380:21)
        at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (C
:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:78:17)

        at [object Object].ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Use
rs\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:709:7)
        at D:\My Work\Protractor\Financial\supplierCategories.js:75:62
        at C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\eleme
nt.js:499:23
        at Array.map (native)
        at C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\eleme
nt.js:498:20
    From: Task: Run it("should have a title") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:81:14)
        at attemptAsync (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1916:24)
        at QueueRunner.run (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1871:9)
        at QueueRunner.execute (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1859:10)
        at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:697:35
)
        at Spec.execute (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:359:10)
        at Object.fn (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:2479:37)
        at attemptAsync (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1916:24)
        at QueueRunner.run (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1871:9)
        at QueueRunner.execute (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1859:10)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (D:\My Work\Protractor\Financial\supplierCategories
.js:2:2)
        at addSpecsToSuite (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:833:25)
        at Env.describe (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:802:7)
        at jasmineInterface.describe (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:3375:18)

        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\My Work\Protractor\Financial\supplierCategorie
s.js:1:1)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 28.377 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

When I'm using Metod 2, following error occurs.

```
1) Protractor Demo App should have a title
  Message:
    Failed: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[value=\"Test Suppli
er Category by Manuli\"]")
  Stack:
    NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[value=\
"Test Supplier Category by Manuli\"]")
        at new bot.Error (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
actor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
        at C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\eleme
nt.js:674:15
        at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:12
4:15)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:406:9)
    Error
        at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\Manuli\AppD
ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:380:21)
        at [object Object].ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (C
:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:78:17)

        at [object Object].ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (C:\Use
rs\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:709:7)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\My Work\Protractor\Financial\supplierCategorie
s.js:81:59)
        at C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modu
les\jasminewd2\index.js:96:23
        at new wrappedCtr (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prot
ractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2468:26)
        at controlFlowExecute (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:82:18)
    From: Task: Run it("should have a title") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:81:14)
        at attemptAsync (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1916:24)
        at QueueRunner.run (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1871:9)
        at QueueRunner.execute (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1859:10)
        at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:697:35
)
        at Spec.execute (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:359:10)
        at Object.fn (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:2479:37)
        at attemptAsync (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1916:24)
        at QueueRunner.run (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1871:9)
        at QueueRunner.execute (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1859:10)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (D:\My Work\Protractor\Financial\supplierCategories
.js:2:2)
        at addSpecsToSuite (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:833:25)
        at Env.describe (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protra
ctor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:802:7)
        at jasmineInterface.describe (C:\Users\Manuli\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:3375:18)

        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\My Work\Protractor\Financial\supplierCategorie
s.js:1:1)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 27.754 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML representation of the `select` element(s) you are working with? Screenshots does not help much here. Also, post the complete traceback of the error. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe , Added. Can you please just look at it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't see the `Test Supplier Category by Me` option in the posted HTML.

Also, it looks like you are checking the `value` attribute, but should be checking the text of the option instead. This could be done with an XPath locator:

```
element(by.xpath("//option[. = 'Utility Bill Expenses']")).click();
```

---

But, I would really look into using a `Select` wrapper proposed here:

- [Select -> option abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723419/select-option-abstraction)

Then, the code would be as simple as:

```
var SelectWrapper  = require('select-wrapper');
var mySelect = new SelectWrapper(by.model('sub_category.category_id'));

mySelect.selectByText('Utility Bill Expenses');
```

Comment: This gives an error called cannot find select-wrapper. :(

Comment: @QualityProducts well, sure, because it is a separate `select-wrapper.js` file you need to manually create. Please carefully study the answer at that linked thread. Thanks.