# CSS containing exact text

Tags: selenium, protractor

Can someone please suggest if there is any way to search for an element with exact text while using cssContainingText. I am using below code but have multiple values in dropdown as below.

```
Value 1
Value 1 Test 1
Value 1 Protractor 1
```

Below is the code I am using.

```
element(by.cssContainingText('option', Value1)).click();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `by.cssContainingText()` is a *partial match* locator by definition. If you want to have an exact match, you can solve it with an XPath expression:

```
element(by.xpath('//option[. = "Value 1"]')).click();
```

And, since you are dealing with `select` and `option`s, see if this wrapper would be a good fit:

- [Select -> option abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28723419/771848)

Comment: Thanks. Xpath worked well for now so I will go with that but will also try abstraction at some point.

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this with `cssContainingText` as well if you use a regexp with an exact match for the second argument, e.g.:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('option', /^Value 1$/))
```

See related SO post here: [Match whole string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/match-whole-string)