# Select option from dropdown in app non-angular

Tags: selenium, protractor

**My goal:**

Select value from dropdown non-angular

**My Problem:**

I'm not finding on the internet any valid option to select an option in a dropdown for non-angular apps

**My dropdown**

```
<select class="form-control" name="seller" required="" onchange="location.href='/dashboard/listings/add?seller='+$(this).val()">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="588a82ec516f550400407f05">a (rafael@rafael.com)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And what did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the "Select -> Option" helper abstraction introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28723419/771848), you can do it this way:

```
var SelectWrapper  = require('select-wrapper');
var seller = new SelectWrapper(by.name('seller'));

seller.selectByPartialText('rafael@rafael.com');
```

Or, if doing it directly using the [`by.name()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.name) and [`by.cssContainingText()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) locators:

```
var seller = element(by.name('seller'));
seller.element(by.cssContainingText("option", "rafael@rafael.com")).click();
```