# How to return a list of available options in a select element in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to retrieve all the options available in `select` element using Protractor. I am having trouble figuring out how to do this because I'm a JavaScript beginner and therefore am having trouble determining how to return the array and not a promise.

I've tried this:

```
getOptions = function () {
    var self = this;
    var availableOptions = [];

    return this.selector.click().then(function () {
        self.selectorOptions.then(function (options) {
            options.forEach(function (option) {
                option.getAttribute("value").then(function (value) {
                    availableOptions.push(value);
                });
            });
        });
    }).then(function () {
        return availableOptions;
    });
};
```

This returns a promise and not the array which I want. I also tried this:

```
getOptions = function () {
    var self = this;
    var availableOptions = [];

    this.selector.click().then(function () {
        self.cloudletTypeOptions.then(function (options) {
            options.forEach(function (option) {
                option.getAttribute("value").then(function (value) {
                  availableOptions.push(value);
                });
            });
        });
    });

    return availableOptions;
};
```

When I do this and call the method from a test and try to print the result, it is 'undefined'. What do I need to do to ensure that the return value is defined and is an array? Barring that, how do I force the promise to resolve?

Comment: There was a nice Select-options abstraction proposed some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28723419/771848.

Comment: I wish this abstraction existed. It would make dealing with these components so much easier.

Comment: Well, it is, you can copy it into your project, require and use..

Comment: The solution proposed in the question returns web elements. I am trying to compose a method that returns a list of domain-specific options. I took that out of the code I posted in my question because I thought it would distract from the question of how to get an array and not a promise or an undefined value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are looking for [`map()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

> Apply a map function to each element within the `ElementArrayFinder`.
>   The callback receives the `ElementFinder` as the first argument and the
>   index as a second arg.

```
getOptions = function () {
    var self = this;

    return this.selector.click().then(function () {
        return self.selectorOptions.map(function (option) {
            return option.getAttribute("value").then(function (value) {
                return value;
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. In my test, I have to invoke it like this to get the value and not a promise:  getOptions().then(function (options) { console.log(options);})