# Select dropdown option by text if same list of class are found in protractor js

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, protractor

I'm working in Protractor and javasript. My page has 3 dropdowns of same class "imageeditor". I want to select the 2nd dropdown and click the option say "Package" by passing the text as parameter.I want the different xpath and css to perform the select option.

```
<div class="imageeditor">
<select class="form-control m-b-sm">
<option>Select Image Style</option>
<option value="image-panel">Panel</option>
<option value="image-package-panel">Package</option>
<option value="image-open-panel">Open</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="imageeditor">
<select class="form-control m-b-sm">
<option>Select Image Style</option>
<option value="image-panel">Panel</option>
<option value="image-package-panel">Package</option>
<option value="image-open-panel">Open</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="imageeditor">
<select class="form-control m-b-sm">
<option>Select Image Style</option>
<option value="image-panel">Panel</option>
<option value="image-package-panel">Package</option>
<option value="image-open-panel">Open</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired `select` element by index:

```
var desiredImageEditor = $$(".imageeditor select").get(1);
```

Now, in order to select an option, you have multiple ways to do so. One is to select the inner option by the class name and click it:

```
var desiredOption = desiredImageEditor.$("option.image-package-panel");

desiredImageEditor.click();  // open up dropdown
desiredOption.click();
```

Or, it should also be possible to just send keys to the `select` element:

```
desiredImageEditor.sendKeys("Package");
```

There is also this [convenient abstraction over `select` and `option`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28723419/771848)

Comment: hi..thanks it works,,i used sendkeys("package"). In the first line what is select mean? the next tag? or its a keyword? if i remove select and just tried with imageeditor, it fails.

Comment: @Nalu yup, the expression inside $$ is a CSS selector. Thanks, glad it worked.

Comment: CSS selector? May i know what other selectors available for css? i googled.but i did not find anything as this example. Can you share any link which helps me learn more of these and to learn other examples?

Comment: And what is the equivalent in xpath ?

Comment: var desiredOption = desiredImageEditor.$("option.image-package-panel");

desiredImageEditor.click();  // open up dropdown
desiredOption.click(); Does not seem to work.NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, option.image-ingredientspanel)

Comment: @Nalu sorry, not sure where is `image-ingredientspanel` coming from - don't see this class in the HTML you've provided..Definitely, look CSS selector syntax up - they are generally more concise and reliable than XPath expressions.