# Get selected dropdown value in protractor selenium

Tags: html, selenium, protractor

How to get selected HTML dropdown value in protractor selenium?
It's printing all dropdown values instead of selected value.
I have tried the following ways:

- `option:selected`
- `option:clicked`
- `option.getFirstSelectedvalue()`

None of these worked.

Can someone help me with the issue?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select -> option abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723419/select-option-abstraction)

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdown implement by HTML Tag: `<select>` and `<option>`, you can use css selector:  `element(by.css('option:checked')`