# Protractor unable to select dropdown option

Tags: protractor, ui-automation

Hi I have been doing protractor test and I'm having a problem with my tests. My ionic app do have a drop down having a model name and I tried to access it using the model name and it works but the problem is it can not select the exact option that i need to select from that dropdown option. It selects only the first one? I wrote the protractor syntax like this.

```
element(by.model('generalPowerOfAttorney.grantorGeneralPowerOfAttorneyForm.region')).$('[value="59"]').click();
```

But this code selects not the value 59 rather value 0 which is the default option. Is there anyone who could help me?

Comment: Can you update your html or ionic code in your question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add the html source to facilitate the answer.

You can use the filter method in order to get the correct element clicked.

```
var elements = element.all(by.model('generalPowerOfAttorney.grantorGeneralPowerOfAttorneyForm.region'));

elements.filter(function(elem, index) {
    return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
        return text === 'value="59"';
    });
}).then(function(filteredElem){
    if(filteredElem[0] !== undefined){
        filteredElem[0].click();
    }
    else {
        throw 'element not found'
    }
});
```