# How can I select a value in a <select> list using Angular's Protractor 0.24 version?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Protractor seems to be getting better every week and I am now using the 0.24 version. Unfortunately I was not able to find out how I can simulate clicking a value from a `<select>` list.

Can someone give me an example of how they select a value from a populated `<select>` or even better point me to a place in the documentation where this is explained.  For reference I did see the question: [How to select option in drop down protractorjs e2e tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599450/how-to-select-option-in-drop-down-protractorjs-e2e-tests) however as things are changing so quickly I would like to know is if using xpath is still the recommended way to do a select or have any users come up with a better solutions with the latest version of Protractor. As I have a lot of coding to do I would like to be sure I am using the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have adapted the code from [@PaulL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2301963/paull) in [How to select option in drop down protractorjs e2e tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20308276/1594933).

```
var selectDropdownbyNum = function (selectElement, optionNum) {
  if (optionNum){
    selectElement.all(by.tagName('option'))
      .then(function(options){
        options[optionNum].click();
      });
  }
};
```

Protractor 0.24.0 "is a big change with lots of breaking stuff". There are described by [Julie Ralph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2316696/jmr) (the protractor main developer) in this [g+ post](https://plus.google.com/114845304720350465605/posts/3qu7E46Lwuw). 
I follow her on google+ to be notified of the new releases.

In this case `findElements` have been replaced by `all`.

Finding good documentations is quite difficult. Often, i walk through the [protractor specs on github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/spec/basic) to find working examples.

Answer (score 1):

I used by.css and it worked fine for me.

```
actionPage.findElement(protractor.By.css('.NEW_CLAUSE_PANEL div:nth-child(2) span select option:nth-child(3)')).click()
```