# What is dropdown protractor code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

Drop-down contain the `ng-model ="text.abc"` and contain visible `text="Test"`:

```
<md-select id="select_55" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" required="" aria-label="queuingModel: SKILL_GROUP" ng-model="text.abc" md-on-close="vm.changeQueue(vm.queue.resourcePoolType)" name="resourcePoolType" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-owns="select_container_56" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="false" style="">
<md-select-value id="select_value_label_51" class="md-select-value">
<span>
<div class="md-text ng-binding">SKILL_GROUP</div>
</span>
<span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</md-select-value>
```

I cannot use this code:

```
element(by.model('text.abc')).$('[value=" ?"]').click();
```

I do not have value of drop-down.

What should be the protractor code for drop-down in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can select a value *by it's text*:

```
var optionToSelect = "SKILL_GROUP";

var dropdown = element(by.model('text.abc'));
dropdown.click();

dropdown.element(by.xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'md-text') and . = '" + optionToSelect + "']")).click();
```

Comment: Now this error occur  
    Failed: Element is not clickable at point (703, 415.5). Other element would receive the click: <div class="md-text ng-binding"></div>

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
element(by.id(dropdownList)).sendKeys("value");
```

or

```
element(by.model(dropdownModel)).sendKeys("value");
```

Comment: I did not understand this.When(/^I select string "([^"]*)" from the dropdown menu with id "([^"]*)"$/, function(string, dropdownList, next) statement can you please elaborate it

Comment: Apologies. I am used to using [Cucumberjs](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) to define my tests. I've updated my answer to remove the reference to cucumber

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
// Select Category
element.all(by.model('dropdown')).each(function (eachElement, index)
{
     eachElement.click();
     browser.driver.sleep(500);
     element(by.model('text.abc')).click();
     browser.driver.sleep(500);
});
```

Hope this helps. :) See [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599450/how-to-select-option-in-drop-down-protractorjs-e2e-tests) for more information.

Comment: I want to click on a specific element of dropdown like Test not for each element this code is not working

Comment: Okay. Can u give me the HTML code of your dropdown ?