# Protracter-helper data-hook attribute error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs

I am trying to access the data-hook attribute using protractor-helpers(var helpers = require('protractor-helpers'), but for some reason I am getting the below error:

```
[12:06:50] E/launcher - Error: ReferenceError: beforeEach is not defined
    at C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\protractor-helpers\dist\protractor-helpers.js:258:2
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xyz\node_modules\protractor-helpers\dist\protractor-helpers.js:498:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xyz\ProtractorWorkspace\Protractor\pos\Test.js:11:15)
```

My conf.js file is as below

```
exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: [
    'features/sample.feature'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  framework: 'custom',
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'features/*.js',
    format: 'pretty'
  }

};
```

Can somebody please help.

Comment: Looks like that package is made for Jasmine considering the source code has `beforeEach(function () { jasmine.addMatchers({ ...`.  Doesn't look like it supports cucumber, but I'm not positive on that.  https://github.com/wix/protractor-helpers/blob/master/src/matchers.js

Comment: Can you also show your test?

Comment: it is failing in the require statement , below is code snippet.

var clickFn = require('../common/ClickFunctions.js');

var SelectDropDown = require('../common/DropDownFunctions.js');
var helpers = require('protractor-helpers');

var startQuote = function(){

 
}

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using protractor-jasmine framework(which is the default framework in protractor) you should use jasmine's hooks -beforeEach, beforeAll etc.
>
> If you are using protractor-cucumber framework you should cucumberjs's hooks/event-handlers - beforeScenario, beforeFeature etc.

For protractor -jasmine hooks please have a look at this link - [jasmine hooks](https://jasmine.github.io/2.5/introduction#section-Setup_and_Teardown)

I see that you are using `protractor-cucumber-framework`, so I would be writing here on how to use the cucumberjs built in hooks.

Firstly you would need cucumberjs node module in your project along with protractor-cucumber-framework module. `npm install -D cucumber`(I prefer it as a dev-dependency)

Current version of cucumber is 2.0(rc-8), its syntax is totally different from older versions. So if you want to launch browser url before every scenario you would have to do something like this -

```
/* Cucumber 2.0 syntax **/

var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function({Before}) {

Before(function () {
browser.get(url);
 });

// You can also specify cucumber tags for scenarios, This hook will be executed before scenarios tagged with @foo
Before({tags: "@foo"}, function () {
browser.get(url)
});
});
```

You could find whole list examples and hooks here - [cucumber hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md)

You could checkout my repo's for more examples-

- [protractor-cucumber-allure](https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-allure) --> cucumber version 1.3.1(older version) different syntax
- [protractor-cucumber-typescript](https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript) --> cucumber 2.0(rc-8) latest version new syntax

Comment: Thanks Ram for the help, but it was not reagarding cucumber hooks , it is regarding data-hook attribute in the dom, please see the below DOM content

Comment: Thanks Ram for the help, but it was not regarding cucumber hooks , it is regarding data-hook attribute in the dom, please see the below DOM content having select tag, i want to select as 'element(by.dataHook('sometext')).click()' for this we need to use npm package 'protractor-helpers' as briefed in the below link, but iam getting the error when 'var helpers' code is encountered.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-helpers


<select class="cui-dropdown cui-dropdown--short ng-pristine ng-valid cui-form-field__control  ng-empty ng-touched" data-hook="quoting.finance.product" >

Comment: There is no element finder with `by.dataHook` instead you should use css selectors in order to find such elements. try - `element(by.css('select[data-hook="quoting.finance.product"]')).click()` , you can also use `by.cssContainingText` checkout this link on how to deal with select attrubutes in protractor - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599450/how-to-select-option-in-drop-down-protractorjs-e2e-tests

Comment: Thanks very much for that ram , this was of very good help , by any chance we can use npm package 'protractor-helpers'  https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-helpers  for cucumber framework?, if yes then it would have been good.

Comment: I am not sure as I have not used them with cucumber!