# Select an Option from a Dropdown List using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, visual-studio-code

```
  <select _ngcontent-c4="" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option _ngcontent-c4="" selected="selected" value="People" ng-reflect-value="People">People</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c4="" value="Quality" ng-reflect-value="Quality">Quality</option>
    <option _ngcontent-c4="" value="Profitable Growth" ng-reflect-value="Profitable Growth">Profitable Growth</option>
</select>
```

I want to find People / Quality / Profitable Growth value from dropdown and click on it.
Please let me know if anyone is having guideline for the same.
TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select option in drop down protractorjs e2e tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599450/how-to-select-option-in-drop-down-protractorjs-e2e-tests)

Answer (score 0):

Below code only according to your give out HTML code:

```
selectOption(from, option) {
  from.element(by.xpath('./option[.="+option+"]')).click();
}

var from = element(by.css('select.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid')));
var option = 'Pepole';

selectOption(from, option);
```