# Xpath / Selenium - How do I grab all of the options in a <select>, excluding the default, given a simple dom?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Working on an automation test using codeceptjs/selenium, I need to read the text of the nodes of a select drop down without knowing what they will be ahead of time and excluding the greyed out default option (since the app will not function until a choice is made).

```
<select id="itemname1">
 <option class="greydefault">How Many?</option>
 <option>6</option>
 <option>8</option>
 <option>10</option>
 <option>12</option>
</select>
<select id="itemname2">
 <option class="greydefault">What Type?</option>
 <option>a</option>
 <option>b</option>
 <option>c</option>
 <option>d</option>
</select>
```

Given the above simple dom, question is how to write an xpath that grab all 4 of the option nodes that contain 6 8 10 and 12. And another xpath that returns all 4 of the option nodes a b c and d.

Here are my attempts that don't work for me:

```
.//option/preceding::option[text()="What Type?"]/following::option[text()="How Many?"]

.//option/following::option[text()="How Many?"]/preceding::option[text()="What Type?"]


.//option/preceding::option[text()="What Type?"] and following::option[text()="How Many?"]


.//option/[preceding::option[text()="What Type?"] and following::option[text()="How Many?"]]
```

The first 2 attempts returns only the node "How many" for me, and the next attempts are invalid.

The output of the xpath query should return each option node other than the default node.

That xpath is put into a function that reads the texts of the nodes, it looks like this:

```
  getElementsText(locator) {
    let driver = this.helpers.Protractor.browser;
    return driver.element.all(locator).getAttribute("textContent").then((result) => {
      return result.toString().split(',');
    });
  }
```

Comment: what is your expected output? from drop down you can select only one item at times?

Comment: Correct, I am not trying to select an option from the list. I am trying to read the text inside of all option nodes excluding the default. So I am running a protractor helper function that looks like this:

  getElementsText(locator) {
    let driver = this.helpers.Protractor.browser;
    return driver.element.all(locator).getAttribute("textContent").then((result) => {
      return result.toString().split(',');
    });
  }

I need an xpath, that returns all of the option nodes for either select node, without returning the default option node.

Comment: Thank you for your question I updated the main post with information specifically about what the expected output of the xpath would be.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29424530/2386774) for a nice wrapper. Once you have implemented that, use `.getOptions()` and ignore the first `OPTION`, e.g. loop 1 to X instead of 0 to X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all `option` elements based on the default one's text (displayed value) in this `select`:

```
//select[option[text()="How Many?"]]/option[not(@class="greydefault")]
```

Get all based on the the parent `select`'s id:

```
//select[@id="itemname2"]/option[not(@class="greydefault")]
```

In both cases you first find the `select` element - in the first, the one that has a child `option` with that text; in the 2nd - the one with that id, and then get all its children (direct descendants) that **do not have** that `class` value.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely confusingly to me, this is working to grab the options in the second list excluding the default, but when I read this I assume it should be grabbing the first set of options excluding the default.

```
.//option[following::option[text()="How Many?"] and preceding::option[text()="What Type?"]]
```

Comment: Nope, not really - `following` and `preceding` work down/up the nodes tree, while these `option` tags are in paralel branches. If that sounds confusing, imagine a pyramid structure - a boss/employee structure. Up the tree will be your boss, then her boss and so on, down - your employee, then her employee etc. A parallel branch is another department - which you don't have anything in common with; yours and the other one will have a common boss somewhere up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css that will fetch all the options except the default.

First List:

```
select#itemname1 option:not(:first-child)
```

Second List:

```
select#itemname2 option:not(:first-child)
```